# Grouping row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe looks like this:

```
In [4]:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( {'a':['A','A','B','B','B','C'], 'b':[1,2,5,5,4,6]})
df
Out[4]:
    a   b
0   A   1
1   A   2
2   B   5
3   B   5
4   B   4
5   C   6
```

I just want to group row which has same value in `column a`. The desired output is like this:

```
    df
    Out[4]:
        a   b
    0   A   1
            2
    1   B   5
            5
            4
    2   C   6
```

EDIT:

I am sorry, actually the desired output may be like this:

```
    df
    Out[4]:
        b
    A   1
        2
    B   5
        5
        4
    C   6
```

Comment: I think you want `df.groupby('a')` (returns a dictionary), although you've typeset it like a MultiIndex.

Comment: should have said, returns something *very like* a dictionary -- but the values are the sub-DataFrames.

Comment: @cphlewis I have tried using `df.groupby('a')`, but how I can get dataframe looks like that?

Comment: Look into MultiIndex.

Comment: Do you need the 0, 1, 2; or just the 'A', 'B', 'C'? Also, is the concern about presentation or something deeper?

Comment: @MarkGraph yes I need `0,1,2`, because in the next step, I want to use `df.iloc[0:29]` something like that.

Comment: @cphlewis I have tried, but still not working

Comment: Why do you want `df.iloc[0:29]` when you've subgrouped it into `a` cases? are you actually going to be choosing all the `a==B` rows, etc?

Comment: @cphlewis I am sorry, the `0,1,2` is not important, I have improved my desired output

Comment: You cannot deceive df.iloc by changing the index the way you propose. df.iloc[0:29] will give you the first 29 rows, regardless of the row label. Perhaps you meant df.loc[0:28], noting loc is an inclusive slice.

Comment: @MarkGraph I have improved my desired output

Comment: Again I ask, is this presentational or something deeper? The simple answer is df=df.set_index('a'). But it does not print out the way you want.

Comment: @MarkGraph actually in my dataset column `a` represents date such as `2014-04-20, 2014-04-20, 2014-04-21` and I want to group the same date  and set as index, after that I want to slice 30 rows which represents 30 days

Comment: @markovzain I think you should ask a new question with that content.

Comment: Pandas has miles of powerful functions for manipulating dates, times and periods of time. If you ask a question on the specific issue, with some good data, you will get a more meaningful response.

Comment: @MarkGraph thanks mark, I have made a new question in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727468/grouping-date-index-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) rather than [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html):

```
In [11]: df.set_index('a')
Out[11]:
   b
a
A  1
A  2
B  5
B  5
B  4
C  6
```

Comment: I want to group the index. Is it impossible or not?

Comment: Why do you want to group the index? is it for cut-and-paste presentational reasons, of will it help you do something analytically?

Comment: You can groupby the index e.g. with `.groupby(level=0)`. But perhaps it's not clear what you want (or why)...?