# Grouping date index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe looks like this:

```
   In [101]:

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( {'date':['2014-06-30','2014-06-30','2014-06-29','2014-06-29','2014-06-29'], 'value':[1,2,5,5,4]})
df.set_index('date')
Out[101]:
         value
date    
2014-06-30  1
2014-06-30  2
2014-06-29  5
2014-06-29  5
2014-06-29  4
```

In here, I want to group index column based on the date value. The desired output should be like this:

```
df
Out[102]:
           value
date    
2014-06-30  1
            2
2014-06-29  5
            5
            4
```

So, if I use df.iloc[0] the output should be like this:

```
2014-06-30      1
                2
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.set_index('date')` needs to assigned to `df` and you coule use `.loc`

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'date':['2014-06-30','2014-06-30','2014-06-29','2014-06-29','2014-06-29'], 'value':[1,2,5,5,4]})
df = df.set_index('date')
df

            value
date
2014-06-30      1
2014-06-30      2
2014-06-29      5
2014-06-29      5
2014-06-29      4
```

Use `.loc`

```
df.loc['2014-06-30']

            value
date
2014-06-30      1
2014-06-30      2
```

Comment: How I can group the index by the date value?

Comment: You could `df.groupby(level=0)` but why would you `df.set_index('date')` then? Before `set_index`'ing the dataframe, you could have `df.groupby('date')`'ed ? But, if your looking to daily/monthly aggrgartions the function, you are better off using `resample` or `TimeGrouper`!

Comment: yes I have thought to use df.groupby, but it will return `groupby Object`. How I can use `groupby` without using function such as `sum`, `mean`, etc and return the dataframe.

Comment: I have used the `resample` but it also need the function such as `sum`, `mean` or etc

Comment: Have a look at the structure of the groupby object by calling its 'groups' property.  This will give you `{'2014-06-29': [2L, 3L, 4L], '2014-06-30': [0L, 1L]}`.  So you can do `gb = df.groupby("date")`, and then `df.loc[gb.groups["2014-06-29"]]` which gives you the same results at `df.loc['2014-06-30']` via a more circuitous route...

Comment: @RobinL in here actually my goal is how to group the date index which has same value and than I use `df.iloc[:29]` to get 30 rows which consist of 30 dates and  as wall as column `value`

Comment: So you want to say: "give me all the rows associated with the first 30 dates".  You can use the groupby method for this.  So you go `gb = df.groupby("date")`.  and then `gb.groups.keys()[:29]` to get the first 30 dates.  You can then use this as your index, so you can go `df.loc[gb.groups.keys()[:29]]`

Comment: @RobinL I have tried your suggestion, but I face an error when I try to set `gb.groups.keys()[:29]` as index. I dont know to do that. How to set that as index in`df`

Comment: Apologies - I probably wasn't clear enough.  I mean that once you've done `df.set_index('date')` as in your original post, you can then pass the first 30 dates as an argument of `df.loc[]`.  In my suggestion, `groupby` is just being used to grab a list of the first 30 dates.